# Inline SVG in CSS within the Jekyll workflow

Tags: svg, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I use https://github.com/GSI/jekyll_image_encode to inline a SVG into my CSS:

```
background: url("{% base64 foo.svg %}");
```

But that adds a base64 encoding overhead. I would like to inline the SVG itself. But for that I need to get rid of this header in the `foo.svg` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

And I need the SVG content to be URL encoded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% capture svg %}{% include img/gnu.svg %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign svgsplit = svg | split: 'svg11.dtd">' %}
{% assign svgpart = svgsplit[1] | escape %}
{{ svgpart }}
```

I think this does it.

Comment: @wintermeyer if a given answer does not work but you find something else that does, answer your own question, do not edit existing answers..

Comment: I hads to take out the escape filter from line 3 as it was outputting the source code of the svg to the html which wasn't really the effect I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

For older Liquid versions this is a work around:

```
{% capture svg %}{% include foo.svg %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign svgsplit = svg | split: 'svg11.dtd">' %}
{% assign svgpart = svgsplit[1] | strip_newlines %}
{% assign svgpart_url_encoded = svgpart | replace: ' ', '%20' | replace: '&', '%26' | replace: '?', '%3F' | replace: '!', '%21' | replace: ',', '%2C' | replace: "'", "%27" | replace: "<", "%3C" | replace: '>', '%3E' | replace: '"', '%22' %}
{{ svgpart_url_encoded }}
```